Bazel-Central-Registry Hosted in Gitlab
I am in a disconnected environment and am hosting the bazel-central-registry in a gitlab repo.  I am trying to specify the registry in my .bazelrc file.  I can get it to work with a local file system path:
build --registry=file:///D:/repos/bazel-central-registry
But when I use the gitlab repo as the registry I get errors that bazel can't parse metadata.json. Is this the correct way to reference the gitlab repo?  Examples I have seen use raw url on github, but I haven't found an example using gitlab repo...
build --registry=http://my.gitlab/my_group/bazel-central-registry/-/tree/dev

This worked, although the url in the browser returns a 404.
build --registry=http://my.gitlab/my_group/bazel-central-registry/raw/dev

This worked, although the url in the browser returns a 404.
bazel build //example:hello-world --registry=http://my.gitlab/my_group/bazel-central-registry/raw/dev
